# How do I get physical address from a logical address on Linux for arm64 architecture?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I have to get a physical address from logical address on Linux. Also I use linux on arm64 architecture (M1 macbook). How do I get the physical address?

```c
unsigned long physical_addr;
pgd_t *pgd;
p4d_t *p4d;
pud_t *pud;
pmd_t *pmd;
pte_t *pte;

pgd = pgd_offset(mm, start); // start is virtual address and I want to get physical address of start
p4d = p4d_offset(pgd, start);
pud = pud_offset_phys(p4d, start);
pmd = pmd_offset_phys(pud, start);
pte = pte_offset_phys(pmd, start);
physical_addr = pte_pfn(pte);
```

I tried like this but I met errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use `virt_to_phys` to convert a kernel virtual address to a physical address on any architecture.  Note that it is up to you to make sure that the page that is referenced can't be moved while you make use of the PA.

Example:  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath11k/dp.c#L250